# How to compare two JSON files and form an single JSON file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Compare the file1.json and file2.json with id values.

If both id values match, then combine both the objects as resultant JSON object and store it in final JSON.

First JSON file (file1.json):

```
file1 = [{
    "id": 1234,
    "appname": "e-commerence",
    "usage": 24,
    "availablity": "1 day"
},{
    "id": 5678,
    "appname": "Hospital",
    "usage": 40,
    "availablity": "30 days"
}]
```

Second JSON (file2.json):

```
file2 = [{
    "id": 1234,
    "language": "python",
    "place": "singapore",
    "ENV": "Testing"
}, {
    "id": 5678,
    "language": "Java",
    "place": "Dubai",
    "ENV": "DeV"
}]
```

Expected final JSON (final.json):

```
final = [{
    "id": 1234,
    "appname": "e-commerence",
    "usage": 24,
    "availablity": "1 day",
    "language": "python",
    "place": "singapore",
    "ENV": "Testing"
}, {
    "id": 5678,
    "appname": "Hospital",
    "usage": 40,
    "availablity": "30 days",
    "language": "Java",
    "place": "Dubai",
    "ENV": "DeV"
}]
```

Comment: load them as dictionaries and run deepdiff https://pypi.org/project/deepdiff/

Comment: I’ve just [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to decode the JSON data, and then compare whether it 
gives you the result you expect:

```
a = json.load("file-a")
b = json.load("file-b")
if a == b:
    print("file-a and file-b contain the same JSON data")
```

If what you care about is the *data* stored in the JSON file, this is the 
correct way to check it.

On the other hand, if you don't care about the data, but you want to 
detect changes to whitespace, blank lines, or other changes that make no 
difference to the JSON data, then there is no need to care that this is 
JSON data. Just treat it as text, and use the difflib library.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html

Comment: The final JSON should have the fields of first and second JSON.  It contains both file1 object and file2 object fields  as final Object                                                   final = [{ "id": 1234, "appname": "e-commerence", "usage": 24, "availablity": "1 day", "language": "python", "place": "singapore", "ENV": "Testing" }, { "id": 5678, "appname": "Hospital", "usage": 40, "availablity": "30 days", "language": "Java", "place": "Dubai", "ENV": "DeV" }]

Answer (score 0):

You should to massage your data for a bit. I post steps. I don't comment so mutch, it is self-explained:

```
    # Loading json's
>>> a = json.load( open("a.json"))
>>> b = json.load( open("b.json"))

    # Show json content
>>> a
[{'id': 1234, 'appname': 'e-commerence', 'usage': 24, 'availablity': '1 day'},
 {'id': 5678, 'appname': 'Hospital', 'usage': 40, 'availablity': '30 days'}]

    # Creating dicts by Ids.   
>>> d_a = dict( [ ( x["id"], x ) for x in a ] )
>>> d_b = dict( [ ( x["id"], x ) for x in b ] )

    # Show dict content
>>> d_a
{1234: {'id': 1234, 'appname': 'e-commerence', 'usage': 24, 'availablity': '1 day'}, 
 5678: {'id': 5678, 'appname': 'Hospital', 'usage': 40, 'availablity': '30 days'}}

    # Merging dicts:
>>> for k,b in d_b.items(): 
...      d_a[k].update(b)

    # show new values
>>> d_a
{1234: {'id': 1234, 'appname': 'e-commerence', 'usage': 24,
'availablity': '1 day', 'language': 'python', 'place': 'singapore', 
'ENV': 'Testing'}, 
5678: {'id': 5678, ...

    # Dump as json
>>> json.dumps( [ x for _,x in d_a.items() ] )
'[{"id": 1234, "appname": "e-commerence", "usage": 24, 
"availablity": "1 day", "language": "python", 
"place": "singapore", "ENV": "Testing"}, 
{"id": 5678, "appname": ...
```